# Decrypt DSN password ENP to PWD

Tags: sybase-asa

I have a file dsn containing encrypted password. I need to get the decrypted password and perform the steps). We are not storing password anywhere else.

Is there any way to get the PWD using some routine or sybase tool?

We are using Sybase version 9.0.2 (DBODBC9.DLL)..pretty old

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Problem in hand: 1. I have database created with password A. created file dsn. 2. password gets changed to B. 3. B is known to me. I need to reset password A into database which is in encrypted form.

Can I either decrypt the encrypted password and then reset it into the DB or reset using encrypted password (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the link.
http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/6636/decrypt-dsn-password-enp-to-pwd

This should give you all information on this.